# Python + MySQL Login system using Twilio API

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql

This is one of my first python projects. I decided to make a semi-complex login system in Python, using MySQL and the Twilio API.
The current features are:

- Multi-account support
- Two-Factor Authentication
- Password Recovery
- Password Change

I want some feedback on the code itself. I'm thinking of making a version 2 that will have a more clean code, since this one is a mess.
Please tell me what I should improve on and good luck into understanding my code.

```
import datetime
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import smtplib
import re

import mysql.connector

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
import random

### Variables - Change them to fit your needs:
use_two_step_authentication = 'true' # Describes it self. True / False
accountSid = "" # Twilio Account SID
auth_token = "" # Twilio Authentication Token
twilio_number= "" # Twilio Assigned Number
client = TwilioRestClient(accountSid, auth_token)
__author__ = 'hiperbolt' # Gotta get some o' that credit xd
cnx = mysql.connector.connect() # MySQL Connector Information
cursor = cnx.cursor()
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) # Mail server, currently set to Gmail
server.starttls()
server.login('', '') # Mail server credentials
EMAIL_REGEX = re.compile(r"[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+") # In case you are curious, REGEX to make sure mail is valid, feel free to make a more comprehensive one
mymail = "" # Mail adress in server.login
###

def combine_funcs(*funcs):
    def combined_func(*args, **kwargs):
        for f in funcs:
            f(*args, **kwargs)

    return combined_func

def to_integer(dt_time):
    return 10000*dt_time.year + 100*dt_time.month + dt_time.day

class login():
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame1 = Frame(root)
        self.frame2 = Frame(root)
        self.entry1 = Entry(self.frame1)
        self.entry2 = Entry(self.frame2)
        self.label1 = Label(self.frame1, text='Username:')
        self.label2 = Label(self.frame2, text='Password:')
        self.button1 = Button(self.frame2, text='Login', command=lambda: self.loginconfirm())
        self.button2 = Button(self.frame2, text='Forgot password?', command=lambda: self.loginhelp())
        self.button3 = Button(self.frame2, text='Go back', command=lambda: combine_funcs(self.frame1.pack_forget(), self.frame2.pack_forget(), initialscreen()))
        self.frame1.pack()
        self.frame2.pack()
        self.label1.pack()
        self.label2.pack()
        self.entry1.pack()
        self.entry2.pack()
        self.button1.pack()
        self.button2.pack()
        self.button3.pack()

    def loginconfirm(self):
        global inputusername
        inputusername = self.entry1.get()
        inputpassword = self.entry2.get()
        query = ("SELECT * FROM credentials "
                 "WHERE username= %s AND password= %s")

        cursor.execute(query, (inputusername, inputpassword))

        if len(cursor.fetchall()) == 0:
            messagebox.showerror("Sign-In Error", "Wrong username/password combination!")
            self.frame1.pack_forget()
            self.frame2.pack_forget()
            login()
        else:
            query = ("SELECT twostepauth FROM credentials WHERE username= %s")
            cursor.execute(query, (inputusername,))
            for (twostepauth) in cursor:
                if '0' in twostepauth:
                    login.loginsection(self)
                if '1' in twostepauth:
                    randomnumber = random.randint(0, 99999)
                    def checkrandomnumber():
                        inputrandomnumber = self.entry1.get()
                        if int(inputrandomnumber) == int(randomnumber):
                            login.loginsection(self)
                        else:
                            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Two-Step Authentication has failed!")
                            self.frame1.pack_forget()
                            self.frame2.pack_forget()
                            login()
                    query = "SELECT phonenumber FROM credentials WHERE username= %s"
                    cursor.execute(query, (inputusername,))
                    for (phonenumber) in cursor:
                        receiver = phonenumber

                    msg = "Here is your loginsystem acess code: %s" % str(randomnumber)
                    message = client.messages.create(to=receiver, from_=twilio_number, body=msg)
                    self.frame1.pack_forget()
                    self.frame2.pack_forget()
                    self.frame1 = Frame(root)
                    self.frame2 = Frame(root)
                    self.label1 = Label(self.frame1, text='Authentication Code:')
                    self.entry1 = Entry(self.frame2)
                    self.button1 = Button(self.frame2, text='Submit', command=lambda: checkrandomnumber())
                    self.frame1.pack()
                    self.frame2.pack()
                    self.label1.pack()
                    self.entry1.pack()
                    self.button1.pack()
                else:
                    login.loginsection(self)
    def loginhelp(self):
        self.frame1.pack_forget()
        self.frame2.pack_forget()
        self.frame1 = Frame(root)
        self.frame2 = Frame(root)
        self.label1 = Label(self.frame1, text='Enter username:')
        self.entry1 = Entry(self.frame1)
        self.button1 = Button(self.frame2, text='Recover password', command=lambda: self.loginhelpconfirm())
        self.button2 = Button(self.frame2, text='Go back', command=lambda: combine_funcs(self.frame1.pack_forget(), self.frame2.pack_forget(), login()))
        self.frame1.pack()
        self.frame2.pack()
        self.label1.pack()
        self.entry1.pack()
        self.button1.pack()
        self.button2.pack()

    def loginhelpconfirm(self):
        self.recoverusername = self.entry1.get()
        query = ("SELECT Date, username FROM passwordrecover WHERE username= %s")
        cursor.execute(query, (self.recoverusername, ))
        if len(cursor.fetchall()) != 0:
            cursor.execute(query, (self.recoverusername,))
            for (Date, username) in cursor:
                print(datetime.date.today())
                print(Date)
                diff = to_integer(datetime.date.today()) - to_integer(Date)
                print(diff)
                if diff <= 1:
                    messagebox.showerror("Error", "Password was recovered already in the last 24 hours!")
                    self.frame1.pack_forget()
                    self.frame2.pack_forget()
                    self.loginhelp()
                    return

        query = ("SELECT email, password FROM credentials WHERE username= %s")

        cursor.execute(query, (self.recoverusername, ))
        if len(cursor.fetchall()) == 0:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Wrong username!")
            self.frame1.pack_forget()
            self.frame2.pack_forget()
            self.loginhelp()
        else:
            cursor.execute(query, (self.recoverusername,))
            for (email, password) in cursor:
                me = mymail
                you = email
                msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
                msg['Subject'] = "Link"
                msg['From'] = me
                msg['To'] = you
                text = "Hello %s!\nHow are you?\nSomeone requested your password!\nHere it is: %s!\n \nHave a good one!" % (
                email, password)
                html = """\
                    <html>
                      <head></head>
                      <body>
                        <p>Hello %s!<br>
                           How are you?<br>
                           Someone requested your password!<br>
                           Here it is: %s<br>

                           Have a good one!<br>
                        </p>
                      </body>
                    </html>
                    """ % (email, password)

                part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
                part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
                msg.attach(part1)
                msg.attach(part2)
                try:
                    server.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
                    server.quit()
                    messagebox.showinfo("Sucess", "An email was sent with your password")
                    query = ("INSERT INTO passwordrecover (Date, username) VALUES (%s, %s)")
                    cursor.execute(query, (datetime.date.today(), self.recoverusername,))
                    cnx.commit()
                except smtplib.SMTPException:
                    messagebox.showerror("Error!", "An error occurred sending this email, that's all we know.")
                    self.frame1.pack_forget()
                    self.frame2.pack_forget()
                    self.loginhelp()

    def loginsection(self):
        self.frame1.pack_forget()
        self.frame2.pack_forget()
        self.frame1 = Frame(root)
        self.frame2 = Frame(root)
        self.label1 = Label(self.frame1, text='Hello ' + inputusername + '!')
        self.button1 = Button(self.frame2, text='Change password', command=lambda: login.changepassword(self))
        self.button2 = Button(self.frame2, text='Logout', command=lambda: login.logout(self))
        self.button3 = Button(self.frame2, text='Delete', command=lambda: login.delete(self))
        self.button4 = Button(self.frame2, text='Two-Step Authentication', command=lambda: login.twostepauth(self))
        self.frame1.pack()
        self.frame2.pack()
        self.label1.pack()
        self.button1.pack()
        self.button2.pack()
        self.button3.pack()
        self.button4.pack()

    def changepassword(self):
        self.frame1.pack_forget()
        self.frame2.pack_forget()
        self.frame1 = Frame(root)
        self.frame2 = Frame(root)
        self.entry1 = Entry(self.frame1)
        self.entry2 = Entry(self.frame2)
        self.entry3 = Entry(self.frame2)
        self.label1 = Label(self.frame1, text='Old Password:')
        self.label2 = Label(self.frame2, text='New Password:')
        self.label3 = Label(self.frame2, text='Re-Enter New Password:')
        self.button1 = Button(self.frame2, text='Change password', command=lambda: self.changepasswordconfirm())
        self.button2 = Button(self.frame2, text='Go back',
                              command=lambda: combine_funcs(self.frame1.pack_forget(), self.frame2.pack_forget(),
                                                            login.loginsection(self)))
        self.frame1.pack()
        self.frame2.pack()
        self.label1.pack()
        self.label2.pack()
        self.entry1.pack()
        self.entry2.pack()
        self.label3.pack()
        self.entry3.pack()
        self.button1.pack()
        self.button2.pack()

    def changepasswordconfirm(self):
        query = ("SELECT * FROM credentials WHERE username= %s AND password= %s;")

        self.oldpassword = self.entry1.get()
        self.newpassword = self.entry2.get()
        self.newpassword2 = self.entry3.get()

        cursor.execute(query, (inputusername, self.oldpassword))
        if len(cursor.fetchall()) == 0:
            messagebox.showerror("Wrong password!", "The password entered is incorrect!")
            login.changepassword(self)
        else:
            if self.newpassword == self.newpassword2:
                update_password = ("UPDATE credentials SET password = %s WHERE username = %s")
                cursor.execute(update_password, (self.newpassword, inputusername))
                cnx.commit()
                messagebox.showinfo("Sucess!", "Password was altered sucessfully!")
                login.loginsection(self)
            else:
                messagebox.showerror("Password don't match!", "The password do not match!")
                login.changepassword(self)

    def logout(self):
        cursor.close()
        cnx.close()
        root.quit()

    def delete(self):
        self.frame1.pack_forget()
        self.frame2.pack_forget()
        self.frame1 = Frame(root)
        self.frame2 = Frame(root)
        self.label1 = Label(self.frame1, text='Enter your password:')
        self.entry1 = Entry(self.frame2)
        self.button1 = Button(self.frame2, text='Delete!', command=lambda: login.deleteconfirm(self))
        self.button2 = Button(self.frame2, text='Go back',
                              command=lambda: combine_funcs(self.frame1.pack_forget(), self.frame2.pack_forget(),
                                                            login.loginsection(self)))
        self.frame1.pack()
        self.frame2.pack()
        self.label1.pack()
        self.entry1.pack()
        self.button1.pack()
        self.button2.pack()

    def deleteconfirm(self):
        query = ("SELECT * FROM credentials WHERE username= %s AND password= %s;")

        password = self.entry1.get()
        cursor.execute(query, (inputusername, password))
        if len(cursor.fetchall()) == 0:
            messagebox.showerror("Error!", "Wrong password!")
            login.delete(self)
        else:
            delete_account = ("DELETE FROM credentials WHERE username= %s")
            cursor.execute(delete_account, (inputusername,))
            messagebox.showinfo("Sucess!", 'Your account has been deleted!')
            cnx.commit()
            cursor.close()
            cnx.close()
            root.quit()

    def twostepauth(self):
        query = ("SELECT twostepauth FROM credentials WHERE username= %s")
        self.CheckVar1 = IntVar(root)
        cursor.execute(query, (inputusername, ))
        for (twostepauth) in cursor:
            if '1' in twostepauth:
                global authstatus
                authstatus = 1
                self.CheckVar1.set(1)
            elif '0' in twostepauth:
                self.CheckVar1.set(0)
            else:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "Your account does not support twostepauthentication")
                self.loginsection()
                return
            self.frame1.pack_forget()
            self.frame2.pack_forget()
            self.frame1 = Frame(root)
            self.frame2 = Frame(root)
            self.label1 = Label(self.frame1, text='Enable/Disable Two-Step Authentication')
            self.checkbox1 = Checkbutton(self.frame2, variable=self.CheckVar1)
            self.button1 = Button(self.frame2, text='Go back', command=lambda: combine_funcs(self.frame1.pack_forget(), self.frame2.pack_forget(), login.loginsection(self)))
            self.frame1.pack()
            self.frame2.pack()
            self.label1.pack()
            self.checkbox1.pack()
            self.button1.pack()
            def callback(*args):
                query = ("UPDATE credentials SET twostepauth= %s WHERE username= %s")
                if not self.CheckVar1.get():
                    cursor.execute(query, ('0', inputusername,))
                elif self.CheckVar1.get():
                    cursor.execute(query, ('1', inputusername,))
                cnx.commit()
            self.CheckVar1.trace("w", callback)
class register():
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame1 = Frame(root)
        self.frame2 = Frame(root)
        self.entry1 = Entry(self.frame1)
        self.entry2 = Entry(self.frame2)
        self.entry3 = Entry(self.frame2)
        self.entry4 = Entry(self.frame2)
        self.entry5 = Entry(self.frame2)
        self.label1 = Label(self.frame1, text='Username:')
        self.label2 = Label(self.frame2, text='Password:')
        self.label3 = Label(self.frame2, text='Re-Enter Password:')
        self.label4 = Label(self.frame2, text='E-Mail:')
        self.label5 = Label(self.frame2, text='Phone Number:')
        self.button1 = Button(self.frame2, text='Register', command=lambda: self.registerconfirm())
        self.button2 = Button(self.frame2, text='Go back', command=lambda: combine_funcs(self.frame1.pack_forget(), self.frame2.pack_forget(), initialscreen()))
        self.frame1.pack()
        self.frame2.pack()
        self.label1.pack()
        self.label2.pack()
        self.entry1.pack()
        self.entry2.pack()
        self.label3.pack()
        self.entry3.pack()
        self.label4.pack()
        self.entry4.pack()
        self.label5.pack()
        self.entry5.pack()
        self.button1.pack()
        self.button2.pack()

    def registerconfirm(self):
        query = ("SELECT * FROM credentials "
                 "WHERE username= %s OR email= %s OR phonenumber= %s")
        desiredusername = self.entry1.get()
        desiredpassword = self.entry2.get()
        desiredpassword2 = self.entry3.get()
        email = self.entry4.get()
        phone_number = self.entry5.get()

        if not EMAIL_REGEX.match(email):
            messagebox.showerror("Invalid Email", "The email you entered is invalid!")
            self.frame1.pack_forget()
            self.frame2.pack_forget()
            register()
        else:
            cursor.execute(query, (desiredusername, email, phone_number,))
            if len(cursor.fetchall()) == 0:
                if desiredpassword2 == desiredpassword:
                    add_credential = ("INSERT INTO credentials "
                                      "(username, password, created, email, phonenumber) "
                                      "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")
                    add_credential_auth = ("INSERT INTO credentials "
                                           "(username, password, created, email, twostepauth, phonenumber) "
                                           "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, '0', %s)")
                    if use_two_step_authentication == 'true':
                        cursor.execute(add_credential_auth, (desiredusername, desiredpassword, str(datetime.date.today()), email, phone_number))
                        cnx.commit()
                        messagebox.showinfo("Sucess!", "Account Registered!")
                        root.quit()
                        cursor.close()
                        cnx.close()
                    elif use_two_step_authentication == 'false':
                        cursor.execute(add_credential, (
                        desiredusername, desiredpassword, str(datetime.date.today()), email, phone_number))
                        cnx.commit()
                        messagebox.showinfo("Sucess!", "Account Registered!")
                        combine_funcs(self.frame1.pack_forget(), self.frame2.pack_forget(), initialscreen())
                    else:
                        cursor.execute(add_credential, (
                            desiredusername, desiredpassword, str(datetime.date.today()), email, phone_number))
                        cnx.commit()
                        messagebox.showinfo("Sucess!", "Account Registered!")
                        messagebox.showwarning("Warning","Variable misconfigured in source file - Variable: use_two_step_authentication")
                        combine_funcs(self.frame1.pack_forget(), self.frame2.pack_forget(), initialscreen())
                else:
                    messagebox.showerror("Password don't match!", "The password do not match!")
                    self.frame1.pack_forget()
                    self.frame2.pack_forget()
                    register()
            else:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "This username/email/phone number is taken!")
                self.frame1.pack_forget()
                self.frame2.pack_forget()
                register()


def initialscreen():
    root.geometry('500x400')
    root.title('Login System')
    frame1 = Frame(root)
    frame2 = Frame(root)
    label1 = Label(frame1, text='Welcome to the login program!', font=5)
    button1 = Button(frame2, text='Login',
                     command=lambda: combine_funcs(frame1.pack_forget(), frame2.pack_forget(), login()))
    button2 = Button(frame2, text='Register',
                     command=lambda: combine_funcs(frame1.pack_forget(), frame2.pack_forget(), register()))
    frame1.pack()
    frame2.pack()
    label1.pack()
    button1.pack()
    button2.pack()
    root.mainloop()


root = Tk()
initialscreen()
```

Comment: small bump @Mathias Ettinger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Style

I suggest you to read through [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the official Python style guide to cleanup your various nammings and spacing issues. Ultimately, it is not necessarily about picking a style, but rather being consistent using such style, which you are not, and it impairs readability.

You also don't really need to store that much into your classes as most of the widgets/containers are not reused accross the various methods.

## Callables

What bothers me the most in this code is the way you define lambdas to call functions with no arguments.

```
self.button1 = Button(self.frame2, text='Login', command=lambda: self.loginconfirm())
self.button2 = Button(self.frame2, text='Forgot password?', command=lambda: self.loginhelp())
self.button1 = Button(self.frame2, text='Submit', command=lambda: checkrandomnumber())
self.button1 = Button(self.frame2, text='Recover password', command=lambda: self.loginhelpconfirm())
```

are better written

```
self.button1 = Button(self.frame2, text='Login', command=self.loginconfirm)
self.button2 = Button(self.frame2, text='Forgot password?', command=self.loginhelp)
self.button1 = Button(self.frame2, text='Submit', command=checkrandomnumber)
self.button1 = Button(self.frame2, text='Recover password', command=self.loginhelpconfirm)
```

I also have a hard time believing that the way you call `combine_funcs` produces correct results. Well it works, but not as it should:

```
self.button3 = Button(self.frame2, text='Go back', command=lambda: combine_funcs(self.frame1.pack_forget(), self.frame2.pack_forget(), initialscreen()))
```

when clicking the button, the `lambda` will execute, calling `combine_funcs` with the result of `self.frame1.pack_forget()`, `self.frame2.pack_forget()` and `initialscreen()`. At this point, all 3 functions has been executed and `combine_funcs` executes with their result (`None, None, None`), returning a callable that will crash when called because `None` (which will be `f` in `combine_funcs`) is not callable.

You should instead write:

```
self.button3 = Button(self.frame2, text='Go back', command=combine_funcs(self.frame1.pack_forget, self.frame2.pack_forget, initialscreen))
```

As you pass callables to `combine_funcs` so the call `f(*args, **kwargs)` will not fail. And since `combine_funcs` returns a callable too, you can use it as the `command` parameter.

## Passwords

An other bad idea here is to store passwords as plain text in the database. Even worse, sending them as plain text in emails.

Instead you should look into the [`hashlib` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib) and only store hashes in your database. Whenever someone tries to authenticate, you hash the provided value and compare it to the hash stored in the database.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will take all of this into consideration and improve my code!